# Uable to register dll using regsvr32

Tags: c++, com, directshow, regsvr32

I developed a com filter on c++ using direct show. It works completely fine on the system I developed it on but I am unable to register it on any other system
Following error appears every time I try to  register it

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are using a Release build on the non-development systems.

Comment: The usual problem is that this DLL has a dependency on another DLL that you forgot to copy.  The CRT dlls are the usual ones.  Building with /MT instead of /MD is one solution, the other one is deploying the [relevant VC redist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).  But realistically a DirectShow component should always have an installer.